# Screenshot captcha using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, screenshot, html2canvas

I'm trying to Screenshot a captcha using html2canvas js Library, but it didn't take the current captcha, it's like it reload the captcha link and then takes the Screenshot,

please check the link

http://jsfiddle.net/f0mqy9vh/

What i tried so far

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#divPage"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
               },
                       allowTaint: true,
                    taintTest: false
         });
         html2canvas($("#btnSave"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
               },
                       allowTaint: true,
                    taintTest: false
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: if there's no way to do that using html2canvas, is there's any other js libraries to take that captcha Screenshot ? or to read the captcha value ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Your fiddle appears to work correctly in firefox but not on chrome.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere you're right, it's working in Firefox, thanks